# Displaying random numbers to the console

Tags: c++, random

I would like to make a program that shows on the console 10 random numbers but I don't know how to generate more than one number

What I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
   srand ( time(NULL) ); 
   int v1 = rand() % 100; 
   cout << v1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, that's won't compile in either language.

Comment: Normally you'd use a `for` loop to repeat the last two lines 10 times.

Comment: It it does , all you need to add are the includes because if you see the ; mean a new line , does not need to be each line/code

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << rand() % 100 << endl;
    }   
}
```

Or, if you really mean C even though your sample code is in C++, this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", rand() % 100);
    }   
}
```

In response to comments from the original questioner, here is a version that reports the values on a single line and the sum of the values on a separate line at the end:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int sum = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        int random_val = rand() % 100;

        sum += random_val;

        cout << random_val << " ";
    }   
    cout << endl << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , did you know how to add it in only one line by spaces? Not like 10 numers = 10 lines

Comment: @user1638487 Change the `cout` line to this: `cout << rand() % 100 << " ";` and then at the end (just after the closing brace for the `for` loop) add this line: `cout << endl;`. There will be a trailing space in your output, but this shouldn't be a problem with just 10 numbers in the output.

Comment: Thanks again , last question... Is there any way to add the random numbers? Lets say that the result is 1 2 3 4 5 , well I would like to call a function that do 1+2+3+4+5 and show the result with cout

Comment: @user1638487 Declare an integer variable to store the sum of your random numbers as follows: `int sum = 0;` (put this above the call to `srand`.) Inside the `for` loop, replace the `cout` line with `sum += rand % 100;`. Change the `cout << endl;` line after the for loop to `cout << sum << endl;`